# Understanding Web session id WRT rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies, crystal-lang, kemal

I'm working on a way to carry sessions between a Rails app, and a [Kemal](http://kemalcr.com/) app. I can do this manually for now, but there's this [library for kemal](https://github.com/kemalcr/kemal-session) that allows for extending how sessions are handled. I have started it [here](https://github.com/jwoertink/kemal-session-client-engine).

My question is, when I decrypt a session cookie value from rails, I'm given a hash that contains a `session_id` key with some value like `0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661`. How is this `session_id` generated? When I extend the engine [here](https://github.com/jwoertink/kemal-session-client-engine/blob/master/src/kemal-session-client-engine.cr#L24), would this be the same session_id I would need to pass around? Or would the entire session cookie value be considered the "id"?

Here's a sample of how it's decrypted in rails:

```
secret_key_base = "a0aaa0a00a000a00a0a0aa00a0aa000a000aa0a0a0a0a0000a0000a00aaa00000000aa0aa00000000a00000a000a000000a00aaa0a0000000a0000a0a0aaa000"
key_generator = ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator.new(ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(secret_key_base, iterations: 1000))
secret = key_generator.generate_key("encrypted cookie")
sign_secret = key_generator.generate_key("signed encrypted cookie")
encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, sign_secret, serializer: JSON)
hash = encryptor.decrypt_and_verify("SOME_REALLY_LONG_STRING")
puts hash["session_id"] #=> 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
```

EDIT (for clarification): I currently have 2 rails apps that share session between them. My goal is to replace one of the rails apps with a kemal app. I currently have this working from rails -> kemal, but going kemal -> rails doesn't work.

How does rails generate that `session_id` value? Should I be generating this value the same way in kemal?

Comment: Start with the [rails guides article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) and [Justin Wiess excellent blog post](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) on the topic.

Comment: Basically the ID is a hash which is used to identify a unique session with a session storage - which by default is  `EncryptedCookieStorage`. Bit if I where you I would avoid using sessions and use a token based system instead if possible.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the link. I'll read up on that. The goal I'm trying to achieve is replace a rails app with a kemal app where I have 2 rails apps that share the same secret_key_base and session. I thought about doing a token auth, but I wanted it to be seamless.

Comment: Hmm, in that case you will want to switch the session storage to Memcached/Redis. That way you can just use the session id cookie on both Rails and Kemal and have it point to the same memory store. It gets you around the whole cookie encryption problem. (well at least for the store). https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli

Comment: You still need match the encryption/decryption of the session id cookie so that it can be set and used by both Rails and Kemal. They need to use the same algorith and salt (the application secret).

Comment: Yeah, I'm already doing that and it works going from rails -> kemal. Going the other way doesn't work. My guess was that `session_id` is wrong. I'm not sure how rails makes that id, and if that's what I would use in my kemal shard.

Comment: "The session ID is generated using SecureRandom.hex which generates a random hex string using platform specific methods (such as OpenSSL, /dev/urandom or Win32) for generating cryptographically secure random numbers. Currently it is not feasible to brute-force Rails' session IDs." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-id